# Neo4j: Since yesterday connection problems after updates

Tags: neo4j, connection, cypher

Since yesterday after updating my version of Neo4j I have problems with the connection and every time I want to access my DB I have the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have another instance of neo4j running somewhere.

Stop that one and restart this instance in Neo4j Desktop.